# How do I remove Fedora Linux boot up selection?

Tags: linux, boot, fedora

After installation of Fedora Linux in VMware Fusion I now have two boot up selections.

Second one was probably created after I force shut down Fedora when it froze during installation.

Here is a screenshot to make it more clear what I am talking about.

Update:
It turned out to be a non-VMware issue. Tags removed. Question name changed.

[image: VMware Fusion Boot up]

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with vmware or vmware-fusion and those tags should be removed.

Comment: I didn't know that. ok.

Answer (score 0):

Run [`sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2?rd=Grub2) within Fedora to scan your system for installations and re-create the menu, hopefully correcting any inconsistencies.

Comment: I ran this command and made reboot. Second selection is still there.

Comment: I hadn't pasted the full command line - try again?

Comment: I tried. Got this response: [link](http://pastebin.com/CL7a6p47). Nothing changed.

Comment: As you can see, the menu entry is generated for the "rescue" kernel/initramfs. If you delete them (or better, find out which package own them and uninstall it with `yum`/`dnf`) and run that command again, the entry will be removed.

Comment: Still I don't see why you want the entry to be removed. Are you actually looking for a way to decrease the timeout of the menu?